# Prevent keypress whilst shift key is held

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prevent certain keys from being entered into an input box, but only if that particular key is pressed **whilst the <kbd>shift</kbd> key is held**:

```
$('selector').keydown(function(e) {
  console.log(e.shiftKey);
  if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 51) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Disallowed');
  }
});
```

The alert fires but the character still appears in the text box.

I've tried searching around for an explanation as to why this happens but to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated!

**edit**

Removing the `alert` seems to fix the problem (which seems bizarre), I'd really love to know why it behaves in this way though, it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Thanks

Comment: replacing `e.preventDefault();` with `return false` will do the job

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't appear to work :|

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GEngv/ works just fine (in firefox)!

Comment: Seems really odd, the alert fires but the key still appears in the text box.. I've tested in FF 14.x and Chrome 19.x

Comment: Are you trying to prevent a pound sign `£` from being typed into an input box? If so, wouldn't it be easier or more usable to just validate the field or ignore/allow the symbol? There are a few ways to get a pound sign into a field, drag/drop, copy/paste, ALT+0163 (on the numeric keypad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is now: why does `alert()` make a difference?

`alert` is a funny statement (and `confirm` and `prompt`), it suspends execution of your JavaScript, but frees up any other browser processing that was waiting for your JavaScript to execute.  It can interfere with debugging quite a lot.

The browser won't respond to your `preventDefault()` statement until your JavaScript has finished, putting `alert` in there has suspended your JavaScript, so the browser hasn't received a return status of the event at this point, and unfortunately the `alert` has allowed the browser to process other events, namely `keypress` which sneaks past and hence you see the character you don't want to be typed appear.

You could not use `alert`, or, if you need it (?!) you could issue it wrapped in a `setTimeout`, so that it doesn't block your JavaScript and the result of the `keydown` will lead to the `keypress` being suppressed.

--

Or, you could have used `keypress` in the first place!

```
$('selector').keypress(function(e) {
  console.log(e.shiftKey);
  if (e.which == 163) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Disallowed');
  }
});
```

That still doesn't prevent characters being entered by alternative methods though, so I wouldn't entertain this in the first place, personally.  :-/

Answer (score 7):

Just use **[`e.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)** instead of `e.keyCode`

```
$('#input').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 51) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Disallowed');
  }
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/536/)**

Because, From jQuery doc:

> For key or mouse events, this property indicates the specific key or
>   button that was pressed.The **event.which** property normalizes **event.keyCode** and  **event.charCode**. It is recommended to watch **event.which** for keyboard key input.
>   **event.which** also normalizes button presses (**mousedown and mouseupevents**), reporting *1 for left button*, *2 for middle*, and *3 for right*. Use **event.which** instead of **event.button**.

### Try this on `.keyup()`

```
$('#input').keyup(function(e) {
   var val = $.trim( this.value );
  if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 51) {
    $(this).val(val.replace(/\#/,''));
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/538/)**

​

#### If you're trying to remove pound sign from input then try:

```
$(this).val( val.replace(/\u00A3/g, '') );
```

***Full code***

```
$('#input').keyup(function(e) {
   var val = $.trim( this.value );
  if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 51) {
    $(this).val( val.replace(/\u00A3/g, '') );
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :| the character still appears in the box despite the alert being displayed. I've tested in Chrome 19.x and FF 14.x, thanks for the info regarding `e.which` though, I shall use that from now on! +1

Comment: @deifwud please check my second demo

Comment: Same thing with that one too, the character still appears in the text box :/

Comment: Lol, except SHIFT+3 on my keyboard is `£` of course, `#` has it's own key without SHIFT.  What's the requirement again?

Comment: Sorry Lee I should have been more specific - I am actually trying to capture the `£` key

Comment: @deifwud to remove pound sign, I've edited my answer, check that

Comment: Upvoted for `e.which`, but I think `keypress` would be a better match for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selector').keydown(function(e) {
  console.log(e.shiftKey);
  if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 51) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    //do something, fade an object in...display a message, etc
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

This works for me.

**EDIT**

Added setTimeout function to replicate your desire.

Comment: conditionalize the statements, disable the property, then put a setTimeout and reenable it.