# Prevent keyDown event when shift key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please consider this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vashzmb5/).

I want to filter inputs on my input that user can just enter numbers. It works when I pressed alphabet keys and `shift`+alphabet keys(nothing added to input). But it doesn't work when `shift+1 (!)` and `shift+2(@)` and ... .
Where is my mistake and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Consider changing the input type to `number`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch enter keypress on textarea but not shift+enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178431/how-to-catch-enter-keypress-on-textarea-but-not-shiftenter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block out the input when the shift key is pressed by checking for **e.shiftKey**.

I added the following clause inside your keyDown listener method:

```
if (e.shiftKey) {
    alert("true");
}
```

and saw that it was being called when pressing the shift key.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263593/prevent-keypress-whilst-shift-key-is-held) SO topic, which can be helpful.